# Updating my Github repo from original one

Tags: git, github, clone, git-push

I've `forked` official `moodle` repo from `https://github.com/moodle/moodle` and then `cloned` it on my local machine.

The forked repo consists of about 12-15 branches.

I want to update my Github repo with the original one. The process to do that is:
First I update my local repo using `pull upstream` and then push it to my Gihub repo.

But the command to push is `git push origin master`, where `master` is the branch. 
So, I'll have to do this separately for all the branches?

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin`

Updates to all branches, right? Unless there are conflicts in merges.

If you want to push all branches use --all

`git push --all`

See: http://thoughtpad.cs3.in/2011/06/13/clone-push-all-remote-branches-with-git/

Answer (score 0):

To push all branches to a repo

`git push origin --all`